# Disable CupertinoSwitch Button after a few hours a day

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application that I want to disable the change button(CupertinoSwitch) after 8 hours of use per day, being able to use it as many times as I want within 8 hours of the day.

Below is part of the button code:

```
child: switch (state.driverStatus) {
                    InitialDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    LoadingDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    AccessDeniedDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    OnTripDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    OnlineDriverStatus() => CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (_) async {
                          locator<HomeBloc>().onStatusChanged(
                            const DriverStatus.offline(),
                          );
                        },
                        activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 141, 20),
                      ),
                    OfflineDriverStatus() => CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: (_) async {
                          final homeBloc = locator<HomeBloc>();

                          final locationDatsource = locator<LocationDatasource>();
                          final locationPermissionGranted = await locationDatsource.getLocationPermissionStatus();
                          switch (locationPermissionGranted) {
                            case LocationPermission.denied:
                              final permissionResult = await showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                useSafeArea: false,
                                builder: (context) => const LocationPermissionRequestDialog(),
                              );
                              if (permissionResult == false) {
                                return;
                              }
                            case LocationPermission.deniedForever:
                              showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                useSafeArea: false,
                                builder: (context) => const LocationPermissionDeniedForeverDialog(),
                              );
                              return;
                            case LocationPermission.whileInUse:
                              context.showSnackBar(
                                message:
                                    "Background location updates are not allowed, Please allow this permission in your phone settings for optimal experience.",
                              );

                              break;
                            case LocationPermission.always:
                              break;
                          }
                          final locationServiceEnabled = await locationDatsource.isLocationServiceEnabled();
                          if (locationServiceEnabled) {
                            homeBloc.onStatusChanged(const DriverStatus.online());
                          } else {
                            final serviceEnabled = await locationDatsource.requestLocationService();
                            if (!serviceEnabled) {
                              return;
                            }
                          }
                          homeBloc.onStatusChanged(const DriverStatus.online());
                          locator<LocationBloc>().state.mapOrNull(
                            determined: (determined) {
                              locator<HomeBloc>().onLocationUpdated(
                                location: determined.location,
                                forceUpdate: true,
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 141, 20),
                      ),
                  },
```

I already tried changing the onChanged property, but I was unsuccessful.

I used the following (I left the time in seconds to test):

```
DateTime? workTime;


child: switch (state.driverStatus) {
                    InitialDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    LoadingDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    AccessDeniedDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    OnTripDriverStatus() => const SizedBox(),
                    OnlineDriverStatus() => CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (_) async {
                          if (DateTime.now().difference(workTime!) >= Duration(seconds: 30)) {
                            workTime = DateTime.now();
                            locator<HomeBloc>().onStatusChanged(
                            const DriverStatus.offline(),
                          );
                            return;  
                          }
                        },
                        activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 141, 20),
                      ),
                    OfflineDriverStatus() => CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: (_) async {
                          if (workTime == null || workTime!.day != DateTime.now().day) {
                            workTime = DateTime.now();
                          }
                          final homeBloc = locator<HomeBloc>();
                          final locationDatsource = locator<LocationDatasource>();
                          final locationPermissionGranted = await locationDatsource.getLocationPermissionStatus();
                          switch (locationPermissionGranted) {
                            case LocationPermission.denied:
                              final permissionResult = await showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                useSafeArea: false,
                                builder: (context) => const LocationPermissionRequestDialog(),
                              );
                              if (permissionResult == false) {
                                return;
                              }
                            case LocationPermission.deniedForever:
                              showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                useSafeArea: false,
                                builder: (context) => const LocationPermissionDeniedForeverDialog(),
                              );
                              return;
                            case LocationPermission.whileInUse:
                              context.showSnackBar(
                                message:
                                    "Background location updates are not allowed, Please allow this permission in your phone settings for optimal experience.",
                              );

                              break;
                            case LocationPermission.always:
                              break;
                          }
                          final locationServiceEnabled = await locationDatsource.isLocationServiceEnabled();
                          if (locationServiceEnabled) {
                            homeBloc.onStatusChanged(const DriverStatus.online());
                          } else {
                            final serviceEnabled = await locationDatsource.requestLocationService();
                            if (!serviceEnabled) {
                              return;
                            }
                          }
                          homeBloc.onStatusChanged(const DriverStatus.online());
                          locator<LocationBloc>().state.mapOrNull(
                            determined: (determined) {
                              locator<HomeBloc>().onLocationUpdated(
                                location: determined.location,
                                forceUpdate: true,
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried changing the onChanged property, but I was unsuccessful.

To disable the switch, you set the `onChanged` handler to `null`.

You can set the handler conditionally, based on your variable. Lets assume the variable is called `isDisabled`:

```
CupertinoSwitch(
                value: false,
                onChanged: isDisabled ? null : (_) async {
                // ...
```

You should really write a named method for your handler though, otherwise it gets really complicated to figure out what is going on.